# Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.State’ even though mtl is installed

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

When I tried loading a module containing `import Control.Monad.State`
I got

```
Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.State’
Perhaps you meant
  Control.Monad.ST (from base-4.8.2.0)
  Control.Monad.ST.Safe (from base-4.8.2.0)
  Control.Monad.Fix (from base-4.8.2.0)
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I installed the Haskell Platform, which has cabal and mtl installed.

When I run `cabal update` and then `cabal install mtl`:

```
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
mtl-2.2.1
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

I tried the reinstall flag but it just keeps giving me warnings that I will break other packages so I didn't continue.

My `ghc --version` is `version 7.10.3`. `cabal --version` is `1.22.5.0`

This is what I got when I ran `ghc-pkg list mtl`:

```
WARNING: cache is out of date: Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.10.3-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-7.10.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
ghc will see an old view of this package db. Use 'ghc-pkg recache' to fix.
/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.10.3-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-7.10.3/package.conf.d
   mtl-2.2.1
```

And when I ran `ghc-pkg check` :

```
WARNING: cache is out of date: /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.10.3-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-7.10.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
ghc will see an old view of this package db. Use 'ghc-pkg recache' to fix.
```

And when I ran `ghc-pkg recache`

```
ghc-pkg: /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.10.3-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-7.10.3/package.conf.d/package.cache: you don't have permission to modify this file
```

Comment: How did you run the compiler in order to get the first message? I mean the exact command.

Comment: I did `:l Editor.hs` to load the Editor module. I got the same message when I did `import Control.Monad.State`.

Comment: How did you start GHCi? Via `$ ghci` or `$ cabal repl`?

Comment: I did `$ ghci`.  I also tried `$ cabal repl` but didn't work.

Comment: What happened when you ran `cabal repl`?

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg check` report?

Comment: Possible explanation: `mtl` is installed, but hidden. Alternate possible explanation: `cabal` is using a different version of `ghc` (at your hidden, forgotten request). The output of `ghc-pkg list mtl` would help for evaluating both hypotheses.

Comment: try `$ ghci -package mtl`.  If you have a `.cabal` file include `mtl` in the required packages field.

Comment: I just edited the question to put more info.

Comment: Did you try `sudo ghc-pkg recache`? You might need temporarily elevated privileges to write the cache file, since the path to it is in a Mac OS system directory (`/Library/...`).

Comment: I just tried `sudo ghc-pkg recache` and it worked! Still no idea what happened though

Comment: Open a haskell-platform bug, if you can reproduce it. Seems like the same issue as https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/issues/189, but then for Mac.